# Unable to create JWT in Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, symfony5

I want to create JWT in my app. Went all the way with Symfony Documentation from that links:
`https://symfony.com/bundles/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle/current/index.html#about-token-expiration`
`https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#json-login`
I could not find any solution for that.

My code looks like that:
**Controller method:**

```
#[Route('api/login', name: 'api_login')]
    public function loginUser(Request $request,
                              JWTTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager
                             ): JsonResponse
    {
        $credentials = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

        if (!isset($credentials['username'], $credentials['password']) || !$credentials)
        {
            return new JsonResponse('Missing credentials', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $username = $credentials['username'];
        $password = $credentials['password'];

        $user = $this->repository->findOneBy(['username' => $username]);

        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface || !$this->passwordHasher->isPasswordValid($user, $password))
        {
            return new JsonResponse('Invalid credentials', Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED);
        }

        $token = $tokenManager->create($user);

        return new JsonResponse($user->getUserIdentifier() . $token);
    }
```

**Route.yaml**

```
login:
    path: /api/login
```

**security.yaml**

```
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: username
    firewalls:
        login:
            pattern: ^/api/login
            stateless: true
            json_login:
                check_path: /api/login
                success_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_success
                failure_handler: lexik_jwt_authentication.handler.authentication_failure
        api:
            pattern: ^/api
            stateless: true
            jwt: ~
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: app_user_provider

    access_control:
         - { path: ^/api/register, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/api/login, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
         - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

when@test:
    security:
        password_hashers:
            Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface:
                algorithm: auto
                cost: 4 
                time_cost: 3 
                memory_cost: 10
```

**.env**

```
JWT_SECRET_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/private.pem
JWT_PUBLIC_KEY=%kernel.project_dir%/config/jwt/public.pem
JWT_PASSPHRASE=9c32a9b40d2606c7aed87e3eb8642bd7
```

**lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml**

```
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    secret_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_SECRET_KEY)%'
    public_key: '%env(resolve:JWT_PUBLIC_KEY)%'
    pass_phrase: '%env(JWT_PASSPHRASE)%'
    token_ttl: 3600
```

**That's error**

```
<!-- Unable to create a signed JWT from the given configuration. (500 Internal Server Error) -->
```

That's all what i got. Can anybody see any mistake from me site or can resolve that?

Comment: Symfony has an awesome web debug toolbar, you should be able to get more than just the generic 500 error from that, assuming you are running this in DEV and not PROD.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks for your response. I don't know how but i just deleted whole function and paste exactly same like that i showed and... It works now and generate me a token. Thanks for you for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a custom authentication workflow. You can use a [custom authenticator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authenticator.html).

Here is an example of custom one with JWT.

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Security;

use App\Entity\Account;
use App\Repository\AccountRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\NonUniqueResultException;
use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape;
use Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\Services\JWTTokenManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\{Cookie, RedirectResponse, Request};
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Badge\{CsrfTokenBadge, UserBadge};
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Credentials\PasswordCredentials;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authenticator\Passport\Passport;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Util\TargetPathTrait;

class AppAuthenticator extends AbstractLoginFormAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    public const JWT_COOKIE_NAME = 'BEARER';

    public function __construct(
        private readonly AccountRepository $repository,
        private readonly UrlGeneratorInterface $router,
        private readonly JWTTokenManagerInterface $jwtTokenManager,
        private readonly string $jwtTtlInSeconds,
        private readonly string $hostname
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->router->generate('login');
    }

    /**
     * @throws  NonUniqueResultException
     */
    private function getUserByIdentifier(string $userIdentifier): ?Account
    {
        return $this->repository->loadUserByIdentifier($userIdentifier);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request): Passport
    {
        $credentials = self::getCredentials($request);

        return new Passport(
            new UserBadge(
                $credentials['identifier'],
                function (string $userIdentifier): ?Account {
                    return $this->getUserByIdentifier($userIdentifier);
                }
            ),
            new PasswordCredentials($credentials['password']),
            [new CsrfTokenBadge('authenticate', $credentials['csrf_token'])]
        );
    }

    /**
     * @return  array{identifier: string, password: string, csrf_token: string}
     */
    #[ArrayShape([
        'identifier' => 'string',
        'password' => 'string',
        'csrf_token' => 'string',
    ])]
    private static function getCredentials(Request $request): array
    {
        $credentials = [
            'identifier' => (string) $request->request->get('_identifier'),
            'password' => (string) $request->request->get('_password'),
            'csrf_token' => (string) $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];

        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['identifier']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * @throws  NonUniqueResultException
     * @throws  \Exception  when the JWT_TTL_IN_SECONDS cannot be parsed as an
     *                      interval
     */
    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(
        Request $request,
        TokenInterface $token,
        string $firewallName
    ): RedirectResponse {
        $user = $this->getUserByIdentifier(self::getCredentials($request)['identifier']);

        if (!$user) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Unable to find the user corresponding to identifier');
        }

        $jwtCookie = Cookie::create(self::JWT_COOKIE_NAME)
            ->withExpires((new \DateTimeImmutable())->add(new \DateInterval('PT'.$this->jwtTtlInSeconds.'S')))
            ->withValue($this->jwtTokenManager->create($user))
            ->withDomain($this->hostname)
            ->withPath('/')
            ->withSecure()
        ;

        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        } else {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('root'));
        }

        $response->headers->setCookie($jwtCookie);

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Then in `config/services.yaml`:

```yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        bind:
            $jwtTtlInSeconds: '%env(resolve:JWT_TTL_IN_SECONDS)%'
            $hostname: '%env(resolve:APP_HOST)%'
```

Then in `.env`

```
JWT_TTL_IN_SECONDS=3600
APP_HOST="yourdomain"
```

Don't forget to register your authenticator in `config/packages/security.yaml`:

```yaml
security:
  # ...
  firewalls:
    # ...
    main:
      # ...
      stateless: true
      jwt: ~

      custom_authenticators:
        - App\Security\AppAuthenticator
```